# Why i get here java.io.EOFException?

Tags: java, io

I have the following task:
Given the file which begins with a single long that tells you the offset of a single int piece of data within the same file, write a class that gets the int piece of data.

```
try {
        long dataPosition = 0;
        int data = 0;
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("datafile.txt", "r");

        //Get the position of the data to read.
        dataPosition = raf.readLong();

        //Go to that position.
        raf.seek(dataPosition);

        //Read the data.
        data = raf.readInt();
        raf.close();

        //Tell the world.
        System.out.println("The data is: " + data);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("This shouldn't happen: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Writing error: " + e);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
dataPosition = raf.readLong();
```

You should read the position from the console instead of reading the position from the file.

Use this instead:

```
Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
dataPosition = scr.nextLong();
```

Complete code:

```
try {
        long dataPosition = 0;
        int data = 0;
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("datafile", "r");

        //Get the position of the data to read.
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        dataPosition = scr.nextLong();

        //Go to that position.
        raf.seek(dataPosition);

        //Read the data.
        data = raf.readInt();
        raf.close();

        //Tell the world.
        System.out.println("The data is: " + data);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("This shouldn't happen: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Writing error: " + e);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [RandomAccessFile docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readInt--):

> It is generally true of all the reading routines in this class that if end-of-file is reached before the desired number of bytes has been read, an EOFException (which is a kind of IOException) is thrown.

And for the `readInt` function that you use:

> Throws: EOFException - if this file reaches the end before reading four bytes.

The `readInt` function reads 4 bytes (i.e. 32 bits, the length of an integer).
It does **not** read a decimal number and parse it as integer.

If the long value you read is correct, my best guess is, that you try to read a number (e.g. 123) instead of its binary representation (123 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1011).